# Get Value Json Data to series name Highchart

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I have data Json :

```
0: {nama: "Democrats", drilldown: "Democrats-2010", y: 17}
    drilldown: "Democrats-2010"
    nama: "Democrats"
    y: 17

1: {nama: "Other", drilldown: "Other-2010", y: 14}
   drilldown: "Other-2010"
   nama: "Other"
   y: 14

2: {nama: "Republican", drilldown: "Republican-2010", y: 11}
   drilldown: "Republican-2010"
   nama: "Republican"
   y: 11
```

how get value "**nama**"  to be applied to the highchart data series

Comment: Are you sure with your json data formatting is correct? Please reformat your json data. What I see is there is duplicated data. One with the index and the other one without index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adapt your JSON data to the format required by Highcharts. Example:

```
    series: [{
        data: data.map(el => ({
            name: el.nama,
            drilldown: el.drilldown,
            y: el.y
        }))
    }],
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ncxe1h36/

**API Refernece:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.data

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you would want the bar chart and I have made one. And I assumed the following data is what you want to build with the bar chart. I used jQuery to store your jsonData in the array so you would see step-by-step to get on.

Edited: here is the jsFiddle,
https://jsfiddle.net/kopigod/vn4abw92/1/

```
var namaArray = [],
    yArray = [];

var jsonData = [
    {nama: "Democrats", drilldown: "Democrats-2010", y: 17},
    {nama: "Other", drilldown: "Other-2010", y: 14},
    {nama: "Republican", drilldown: "Republican-2010", y: 11}
];

$.each(jsonData, function(index, value){
  namaArray.push(value.nama);
  yArray.push(value.y);
});


Highcharts.chart('YourChartIdInHTML', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Your main title'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: namaArray
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Y-axis Title'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },
    series: [{
     name: "Test",
     data: yArray
    }]
});
```

Of course HighChart allows you to customize the text when you mouse over the bar.

Comment: series: [{
     name: nama  /// get Value nama
     data: yArray
    }]

I mean name: fill in the value name

Ex: 
series: [{
     name : "Democrats",
     data   : 17
    }]

Comment: the series from mine is a category named Test. You can have multiple categories, you just need to write in array form.